# xcode constraints not working

Tags: xcode, macos, constraints

I'm trying to figure out how the new Xcode constraints work, but it doesn't make sense. I'm trying to set the top, left, and bottom constraints at 0 from view borders for a table view so when I resize the window, my table would resize to fill from top to bottom. But it stays the same size when I resize the window. When I launch the app in full screen, the table is getting set to top to bottom, but if I make the window smaller, I think it cuts half of it off. Seems like it doesn't refresh when I click the resize window button. Anyone have any ideas? Thx

Comment: No problems here in Xcode 5.1. Must be something else you're doing. Maybe post code or a project?

Answer (score -2):

Try this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 . It might be helpful.

Comment: That's for iPad/Phone which doesn't resize screen. I'm having an issue with mac app. If you set up a basic coco app and add a table to it and set top, left, and bottom constraints, and run it. You'll have the table the size of your view, but if you full screen the view, that table will not resize with it. And same for if you start the app in full screen. The table will be full screen, but making the window smaller cut off the table.